# Any bench marks for anomaly detection of intraday or other time intervals for stock prices?

Tags: intraday, anomalies

Is anybody aware of any benchmarks for general anomaly detection of intraday or (other time intervals) for stock prices? I suspect that it is difficult to get agreement on what constitutes an anomaly for this kind of data and it will remain an unsupervised problem and involve injection of synthetic anomalies into market data. [Revisiting Time Series Outlier Detection: Definitions and Benchmark](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=r8IvOsnHchr)